# vbulletin template edit Invalid Page URL

Tags: forum, vbulletin

I am creating a forum in vBulletin for the first time.I have created a sub domain for it(forum.yoursite.com).Now when i try to update the top menu links in the template edit,it says "Invalid Page URL. If this is an error and the page should exist, please contact the system administrator and tell them how you got this message".

Also when i try to access the admincp , I have to write forum.yoursite.com/core/admincp
else i can not access it.

I am using vBulletin 5.1.6 Patch Level 1.

How can I make it working.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I seems you did not install vBulletin properly....
You need to modify config.php file, Write your database name, database username and password in config file, then go to forum.yoursite.com/install/install.php and install the vBulletin, while installing you will be asked to create the admin account.... after you installed the vBulletin then delete the install directory, and you are here.... to edit the navbar you go to the admincp >> style and templates >> >> style manager >> edit template >> Navigation/ Breadcrumb template and edit your links in the template you want to target ... Thanks